# Netbeans 7.2 Git Clone ssh

Tags: git, netbeans, ssh, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I am running Netbeans 7.2 on Windows 7 and cannot clone a repo.  I was previously on Windows XP with Netbeans 7.1 and did not have any issues.

The process that I have always used is to open Pageant and load my keys.  Then in Netbeans I do a `Team > Git > Clone` then type in my repo like this:

```
ssh://server.name/var/git/blah.git
```

and everything would work.

I am not able to do this in Windows 7 with Netbeans.  I get the following error:

```
ssh://gituser@server.name/var/git/blah.git: session is down
```

I can use putty and ssh just fine without using a password when Pageant is running.  I also installed Git Gui / Bash and was able to clone.  I just can't do it in Netbeans.  I am not sure how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before of all you need to register the key. Read [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#github).